# REACTJS xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/registerUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make an API call using axios in React. But I am not sure why I keep getting Error 500. When I check the API and put in the input via URL, it works and give a JSON response but when in reactJS it doesn't and return an internal server error, 500. Can anyone help?

package.json

```
  "proxy": "https://myAPI.net",
```

Register.js

```js
    const handleRegister = async () =>{
      let error = false;
      validateEmail();
      comparePwd();
    
      if(isPwdMatches === false || isEmailInvalid === true){
        error = true
      }
      
      if(error === false){
        console.log(`test`)
        try{
          const response = await axios.post('/registerUser', {
            password: values.password,
            email: values.email,
            name: values.name,
          });
          console.log(response)
          const data = await response.data.data;
          console.log(data)
          setRegistered(true);
        } catch(e){
          console.log(e)
        }
      }
    };
```

Error message:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/registerUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Register.js:98 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Expected output from `https://myAPI.net/registerUser?password=myPassword&email=myEmail@gmail.com&name=myName`

```
{
token: {
kind: "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
email: "myEmail@gmail.com",
displayName: "myName",
idToken: "generatedToken",
registered: true
},
message: "successfully created user profile"
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this, I am pretty new to React and using axios, so any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have to send get request to your api endpoint
as you mentioned [https://myAPI.net/registerUser?password=myPassword&email=myEmail@gmail.com&name=myName`](https://myAPI.net/registerUser?password=myPassword&email=myEmail@gmail.com&name=myName%60) all password email and ... are arm params and you have to pass them as params

```js
const result = await axios.get("yourApiAddress", {params : {email : "",password: "", email : ""})
```

Note that's its possible that you have to post data. if this approach not works try this.

```js
const result = await axios.post("yourApiAddress",{}, {params : {email : "",password: "", email : ""})
```

Hope that you can do this :)

Good luck!

Comment: note that you do not have to `const data = await response.data.data;
          console.log(data)` just simply log `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: I tried both, only the get request works, is there any reason why post request doesn't work from the front end side or does is it something to do with the API that im sending my request to?

Comment: First of all sorry for delay, there are many type of request you can send to an endpoint like get post patch push delete ... . your url is only accept get request. so post method and others will not work

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure The Server Is Up And Running.